# iTunes connect: Developer action needed in IAP

Tags: localization, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

Check out image below. I can't find any solution for that.
I try the few solution like change the description, language etc but it did't resolve.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/RwJ8S.png

This error message got from the apple.

We discovered one or more bugs in your app when reviewed on iPad running iOS 10.3.3 on Wi-Fi connected to an IPv6 network.

We were unable to complete an In-App Purchase.

The steps to reproduce are:

- Launch app- Tap Shopping cart
- Tap Coins
- Tap price to buy coins
- Authenticate
- App freezes

Please see attached screenshots for details.

Next Steps

To resolve this issue, please run your app on a device to identify any issues, then revise and resubmit your app for review.

If we misunderstood the intended behavior of your app, please reply to this message in Resolution Center to provide information on how these features were intended to work.

For new apps, uninstall all previous versions of your app from a device, then install and follow the steps to reproduce the issue. For updates, install the new version as an update to the previous version, then follow the steps to reproduce the issue.

Comment: You should add some more info to your question. What are you trying to do? Was you in-app purchase rejected? Did you receive any communication from the apple review team?

Comment: Ok i edit the description.

Comment: We're you able to reproduce and fix this issue?